# Refrigerator Cabinet Support Requirements?

Tags: cabinets, support

I have a cabinet that I want to put above my refrigerator. It is 2' deep by 3' wide. There is a wall behind and to the left of the refrigerator that I can screw the cabinets into studs on. The cabinet has a rail at the top and bottom of the back (just like all of the other cabinets that I installed. Those were normal shallower kitchen cabinets, but for many of them, this rail and a few screws into studs are the only thing holding them up). Do I actually need a support to the right of the refrigerator, or can I just install it like all the others?

[image: cabinet]

[image: Refrigerator]

Comment: Screws should be enough.  You would want about three inch long, probably #12s or even #14, two on each top and bottom rail, each stud.  Make sure you know where the studs are.  Add support if it will make you happy, but probably not needed.

Comment: The only difference between this cabinet and the other upper cabinets you've installed is the amount of air between the bottom of the cabinet and the surface below it. I installed a cabinet in a corner nearly 30 years ago and only screwed it into the back wall, not the side wall. It's held up just fine through raising 3 kids without a hint of problem.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of screws near the front left can’t hurt. Assuming you’re doing a filler strip on the left, do that first and then figure out padding for the screws.

Don’t just put long screws (on the left) through air, because they’ll deform the cabinet if they’re tight enough.